# PHP mails - duplicate subject

Tags: php, email, duplicates, subject

I have noticed that emails being send from my server have duplicate "Subject" tag in their headers. I am using htmlMimeMail5 library.

Here are few lines of my code to handle mails

```
    $mail = new htmlMimeMail5();
    $mail->setFrom($sender);
    if ($ccRecipient) {
        $mail->setCc($ccRecipient);
    }
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $mail->setPriority('high');
    $mail->setHtml($html, ROOT_FOLDER . '/');
    $mail->setText(strip_tags($html));
    if (sizeof($attachments) > 0) {
        foreach($attachments as $name => $path) {
            if (file_exists($path) AND !is_dir($path)) {
                $mail->addAttachment(new fileAttachment($path, $name));
            }
        }
    }
    $mail->setTextCharset('utf-8');
    $mail->setHTMLCharset('utf-8');
    $mail->setHeadCharset('utf-8');
    if($replyTo){
        $mail->setHeader('Reply-To', $replyTo);
    }
    $sent = $mail->send(array($sendTo));
```

and the result

```
...
To: xxx@xxx.com
Subject: =?utf-8?B?WmF6bm*tZW5hbmEgdWhyY****HphIHByZWRmYWt*dXJ1?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: Mailer
From: xxx <xxx@xxx.com>
Subject: some subject
...
```

There is something hashed in the first subject, what might that be and why it's there? (i replaced few chars for '*' just in case) Could it be considered as spam mail because of that?

Thanks

Comment: it's not hashed, it's base64 encoded. It decodes to something that begins: `Zazn`. Dosn't mean anything to me, but you recognise it as a password or something then you'll probably want to change that pw now. (The stars interrupt decoding of some characters, but I can get most of it).

Comment: it's not pw, it's my original subject if it starts with Zazn

Comment: well I don't know how it's getting in there, but perhaps now you know what it is you'll have a fighting chance of tracking it down yourself.

Comment: which of the two subjects is the intended one.. or both of them are same i.e. text and base64 version of it.

Comment: yes, both are the same